# Why do i get 2 different output from when printing out the sizeof() pointer vs variable

Tags: c, pointers, printf, sizeof, memory-address

Why do i get 2 different output from when printing out the value in the same address?

the pointer ptr is pointing at the index 0 of the accessed Element (bar).

yet is showing me different results?

```
unsigned int bar[5];


int main(){

unsigned int * ptr = &bar[0];

printf("%lu\n",sizeof(ptr)); // Console output : 8 (bytes)
printf("%lu\n",sizeof(bar[0])); //Console output : 4 (bytes)
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `bar[0]` is an integer. `ptr` is a pointer. Why would you expect them to be the same size?

Comment: You're not printing the size of what the pointer points to, you're printing the size of the pointer itself.

Comment: If you want the same results, it should be either `sizeof(*ptr)` or `sizeof(&bar[0])`

Comment: dosen't the sizeof(ptr) witch is pointing at the address bar output the same size? is pointing to it?

Comment: aah .. ok i get it

Comment: Could be worse. You could have been on a 32bit platform with 4-byte pointers, and ended up walking away thinking everything functioned based on an erroneous hypothesis.

Comment: why 8 bytes? how does sizeof() comes up to that?

Comment: ASIDE: you should be `%zu` instead of `%lu` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do i get 2 different output from when printing out the value in
> the same address?

These two statements

```
printf("%lu\n",sizeof(ptr)); // Console output : 8 (bytes)
printf("%lu\n",sizeof(bar[0])); //Console output : 4 (bytes)
```

do not output "*values in the same address*".

The first statement outputs the size of the pointer `ptr` that has the type `unsigned int *`. This statement is equivalent to

```
printf("%zu\n",sizeof( unsigned int * )); // Console output : 8 (bytes)
```

The second call of `printf` outputs the size of an object of the type `unsigned int`. This call is equivalent to

```
printf("%zu\n",sizeof( unsigned int ) ); //Console output : 4 (bytes)
```

As you can see the arguments of the expressions with the operator `sizeof` in these two calls of `printf` are different

```
printf("%zu\n",sizeof( unsigned int * )); // Console output : 8 (bytes)
printf("%zu\n",sizeof( unsigned int ) ); //Console output : 4 (bytes)
```

If you will rewrite the second call of `printf` for example the following way

```
printf("%zu\n",sizeof( bar + 0 ) ); //Console output : 8 (bytes)
```

then you will get the same value as the value produced by the firs call because the expression `bar + 0` has the type `unsigned int *` due to the implicit conversion of the array designator to a pointer to its first element in this expression.

Answer (score 0):

`ptr` is a `unsigned int *`. The size of this kind of pointer is 8 bytes in that environment.

`bar[0]` is a `unsigned int`. The size of this is 4 bytes in that environment.

Maybe you thought you were using `*ptr`?

Comment: why 8 bytes? how does sizeof() comes up to that?

Comment: Re "*why 8 bytes?*", Because that's what the compiler writer chose. Usually because that's the largest pointer supported by the hardware. Technically, I think the x86-64 only supports 48-bit pointers internally, which would be 6 bytes with a byte size of 8 bits. But the registers are 64 bits in size, so the pointers need 64-bit alignment, so making them only 6 bytes would cause two bytes of padding to be added, so nothing is lost by making them 8 bytes in size.

Comment: Re "*how does sizeof() comes up to that?*", `sizeof` is built in to the compiler, and it's evaluated at compile time when the type of expressions is available.